# If Param Set Then Add Class To Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Creating My Custom Scrollbar - In JS File

```
// create scrollbars

var elem = $(this),
...
...
...
var scrollbar = $("<div>")
        .addClass("Bananza-Scrollbar round")
        .css({ height: elemHeight })
        .css(scrollbarPos, 0)
        .appendTo(scroller),

    scrollbarbutton = $("<div>")
        .addClass("Bananza-Scrollbar-Btn round")
        .css({ height: elemHeight * ratio })
        .css(scrollbarPos, 0)
        .appendTo(scrollbar);
elem.css({ width: "-=" + scrollbar.css("width") });
```

### Calling My Custom Scrollbar - On HTML Page

```
$( ".Element" ).BananzaScroll({
    autoHide: true  
});
```

### Question

If `autoHide` equals `true` what is my best option to add the class `.Auto-hide` to my variable?

Comment: Please, if you're going to down rate a question, could you kindly add a reason for doing so, therefore the the person asking the question can improve upon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does autoHide change at all? If not you could do this in your HTML.

```
window.BananzaOptions = {
  autoHide: true
};

$(".Element").BananzaScroll(window.BananzaOptions);
```

then in your js file

```
if (window.BananzaOptions.autoHide === true) {
  $('.some-element').addClass('Auto-hide);
}
```

Edit: In that case, could you just toggle the class form the scrollbarbutton? eg.

```
scrollbarbutton.on('click', function() {
  scrollbar.toggleClass('Auto-hide');
});
```

Comment: No `autoHide` doesn't do anything at the moment, it's a feature I wish to implement to auto hide the scrollbar via adding the auto hide style to the element. I've just added a bit more of my script to my question hoping that helps a bit more with an answer.

Comment: What the autohide is, is that it shows/hides on hover. Alike when you hover over your Facebook notifications drop down menu. `.addClass("Bananza-Scrollbar round")` needs to include `Auto-Hide` if the param is set as true.